# Even after the spanning tree is determined why Root Bridge periodically send configuration message.

Tags: cisco, protocol-theory, spanning-tree

Even after the spanning tree is determined why Root Bridge periodically send configuration message.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The root bridge will keep sending Periodic configuration message with the Root Identifier and the Bridge Identifier would be the same as the Bridge think it is the root, This message will be relayed to all the bridges participating in the spanning tree and each bridge will add its cost to the root before sending it out to all its neighbours on the designated ports, this message will be like keep alive message from the root bridge to all the bridges and in case the root stop sending for max-age time that will trigger new root election.